# Flutter - how to correctly parse Json data when response is nested?

Tags: json, rest, flutter

new to Flutter, I managed to parse this response from a RESt api:

`Provider`:

```
  factory Contacts.fromList(final List<Map<String, dynamic>> list) {
    final Contacts contacts = Contacts();
    for (final Map<String, dynamic> map in list) {
      contacts.add(Contact.fromMap(map));
    }
    return contacts;
  }
```

`then in my service`:

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Contacts.fromList(
          jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>());
```

`when the data comes in this format`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Dave",
        "last_name": "Laweles",
        "email": "dlaweles0@sphinn.com",
```

This all works perfectly,
but now, my dummy API is returning the data in this format:

```
{
    "data": [
       {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Dave",
        "last_name": "Laweles",
        "email": "dlaweles0@sphinn.com",
        }, .....
     ],
    "total": 100,
    "page": 0,
    "limit": 10,
    "offset": 0
}
```

And now I cannot figure out how to change my `Provider` factory constructor to Parse correctly this result object.
Besides the fact that now the response is wrapped in another object, I also need to retrieve the `Pagination` data `(total, page, limit)` as well in my Parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```
actory Contacts.fromList(final List<Map<String, dynamic>> list) {
    final Contacts contacts = Contacts();
    for (final Map<String, dynamic> map in list['data']) {
      contacts.add(Contact.fromMap(map));
    }
    return contacts;
  }
```

And I hope it works for you.

Comment: this was the first thing I tried and does not work
The type 'Map<String, dynamic>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable.dartfor_in_of_invalid_type
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

I will also need to extrapolate the other data on the same level as "data"